# how to find max in array then remove that max element and insert that max element by divided by 2 (floor division) in java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a java program in which we are given an array lets say {20 ,5 ,7 ,9} in this array we have to perform following operations:
(index do not matter here)

1. find max element in this array and delete that element in array.
2. then add the max element again by divided by 2(floor division).
   we can add max element divided by 2 where ever we want.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What specific problems are you facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ArrayList instead of arrays as in Java arrays are static so the size of the arrays cannot change once they are instantiated.Also cannot delete an element and reduce the array size.

```
int max = -Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int maxIndex = -1;
```

iterate over the array and and insert every element to the arraylist

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i : arr){
   list.add(i);
 }
```

Now the array is transformed to an ArrayList.Here we will find the max. Then store the max in the temp variable . Once we delete the max from the list we will use the temp to do floor division by 2 using Math.floorDiv(a,b) function.

```
for(int i = 0; i< list.size; i++){
 max = temp;
 list.remove(i);
 list.add(Math.floorDiv(temp,2));  
   }
}
```

The complete code with the output is given below :

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main{
```

This is the function which will find the max number from the array and then do the floorDiv() by 2 and insert it back.

```
static ArrayList<Integer>solve(ArrayList<Integer>list){
  int max = -Integer.MIN_VALUE;
  int maxIndex = -1;
     for(int i = 0; i< list.size(); i++){
        if(list.get(i) > max){
            int temp = list.get(i);
            max = temp;
            list.remove(i);
            list.add(Math.floorDiv(temp,2));
             }
        }
    return list;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] arr = new int[]{20 ,5 ,7 ,9};
    ArrayList<Integer> list1= new ArrayList<>();
    for(int a : arr){
        list1.add(a);
    }
    Main obj = new Main();
    System.out.println(obj.solve(list1));
  }
}
```

The output is :  [5, 7, 9, 10]

Answer (score 1):

arrays in Java are static so the size of the arrays cannot change once they are instantiated. Thus we cannot delete an element and reduce the array size.

```
int max=-Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int maxIndex=-1;
```

Now iterate over the array and if element is greater than maxValue update maxValue and maxIndex.

```
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)

      {
        if(array[i]>max)
        {
                max= array[i];
                maxIndex=i;
        }
    }
```

Now replace value at maxIndex with MaxValue/2 to solve this.Since position doesnt matter and delete operation has to be performed at the max index might as well place it there or you could use arrayLists to remove element at that index specifically and then using the ArrayList.add() method. Cheers!